# chrome waterfall, why indent?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, http2

After I update to http2, I except all request sent at the same time, but as you can see, some requests are sent at the same time, but some not, why ?

[image]

The 13th request's URL is in the HTML.

Comment: Any relevant codes that can share to us?

Comment: All requests cannot start at the same time because first you only have one. Then as that one gets processed, it initiates further requests. Also, after the document is loaded, even further requests may be sent from JS. We can easily agree that these cannot all start at the same time.

Comment: We all expect things but rarely are given. For instance, I expected a comprehensible question.

Comment: Which website and anything to make them dependent on other resources? Which version of Chrome (may be due to this bug fixed recently: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45384243/google-chrome-does-not-do-multiplexing-with-http2/45775288#45775288), how many resources (may be reaching HTTP/2 stream limit - typically 100 streams on the go at a time).

Answer (score 0):

The color coding in the waterfall shows that a second connection is being opened. If i had to take a guess, i'd think that there's a second domain from which resources need to be fetched.