# Is there a speed benefit to decreasing HTTP requests if using HTTP2?

Tags: http, nginx, http2, sitespeed

AFAIK the entire idea behind reducing HTTP requests to increase website speed lies in HTTP's inability to handle concurrent requests. HTTP2 allows concurrent requests.

Is it still a performance benefit to reduce the number of HTTP requests made?

Or is it more effective to make numerous, smaller HTTP requests as they're handled concurrently?

Or is there a happy medium based on the number of concurrent requests a site/browsers can handle?

I'm specifically using nginx for this, but assume the same question applies equally to apache and other web servers.

Comment: This kind of stuff has to be measured. For example if the actual data you send to the server is about the same size as headers then of course it is better to use 1 request instead of 100. On the other hand using 1 instead of 2 perhaps is no longer worth it. Or if the data is 100 times bigger than headers, again, not necessarily worth it. On the other hand if request handling takes a lot of time, than concurrent approach maybe is bettter. But then what about potential resource starvation, scalability and security? So many questions... There is no simple "better/worse" answer.

Answer (score 1):

HTTP/2 makes requests cheaper - not free.

HTTP requests still have a cost, to look up local cache, build the request, send the request, wait for a response, get the result, decide whether to cache it for next time, process the result...etc. For this reason [browsers can limit the number of requests in flight at once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45384243/google-chrome-does-not-do-multiplexing-with-http2/45775288#45775288).

Servers also typically limit connections to 100 inflight responses at once.

Others have also discovered that [completely forgoing packaging leads to performance issues](https://blog.khanacademy.org/forgo-js-packaging-not-so-fast/), in part for above reasons and also because compression (gzip and brotli) is less efficient for smaller files leading to more bytes having to be sent.

The general consensus seems to be 1) test and 2) bundle less into functional pieces, but don’t go as far as getting rid of it completely.